# Using returned variables in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a query which returns two columns, the Item number and the Row number of that item in the query:

```
Row    Item  
--------------
 1     1234  
 2     5632  
 3     4213  
 4     0912
```

Before I run the query I will know that I am only interested in the row containing Item 5632 and X number of rows following the one containing item 5632 (in this case lets just say rows 2 and 3). However, I will not know ahead of time what row Item 5632 is in.

I would like to somehow say

```
Where Row >= Row of Item 5632  
  And Row <= Row of Item 5632 + X
```

Is this possible to do? Thank you all!

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the query you have now is `SELECT RowNo, Item FROM Tbl`, the following query can replace it and do what you want:

```
DECLARE @Item = 5632
DECLARE @ItemRowNo = SELECT RowNo FROM Tbl WHERE Item = @Item
DECLARE @Qty = 2

SELECT RowNo, Item 
FROM Tbl
WHERE Item >= @ItemRowNo
AND Item < (@ItemRowNo + @Qty)
ORDER BY RowNo
```

If you give me your actual current query, I can update this answer to reflect it.

You may choose to declare less things than what I did if they will be constant, but I'm guessing that you will in fact be `SELECT`ing them from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

More than one way to do this, im more accustomed to nested queries

[Nested select statement in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server)

[SQL nested query in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498662/sql-nested-query-in-sql-server)

More specifically:

```
SELECT TOP 3 a.row, a.item FROM tableA a 
WHERE a.row >= (SELECT row FROM tableA WHERE item = 5632) 
ORDER BY a.row
```

TOP doesnt worry about actual value of ROW, just limits number of retrieved records

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: missing `order by` statement

Comment: there is no `limit` in sql server

Comment: Noticed that as soon as I posted initial answer, i usually try to add links and proof it after seeing how it reads, updating now, thanks for the spot